# Cant figure out IF(number) in Google Sheets macro to hide rows with a zero value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm brand new at this, so I may be way off base here. this is my code:

```
function onOpen() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("To Order");
  var maxRows = sheet.getMaxRows();

  //show all the rows
  sheet.showRows(1, maxRows);

  //get data from clumn B
  var data = sheet.getRange('B:B').getValues();

  //iterate over all rows
  for(var i=0; i< data.length; i++){
    //compare first character, if asterisk, then hide row
    if(Number == "0"){
      sheet.hideRows(i+1);
    }
  }
}
```

My trouble seems to be that the if(number) isn't only selecting cells with 0 to hide. please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in the question compares an undefined variable called `Number` with `"0"` using the abstract equality comparator. This comparison always will return false.

Instead of `Number`, use `data[i][0]`.

Comment: That did it!! i really really appreciate it!